# How to get stdout from pxssh process in Python

Tags: python

I have this code written in Python that runs program on remote server:

```
import pxssh
w=pxssh.pxssh()
w.login(blade11,'root','')
w.sendline('cd /home/*/incoming/')
w.prompt()
w.sendline('./program')
w.prompt()
```

When I run the same program via Putty I get output of execution of './program'
How can I get same output when running program throught python script?